# Does a discontinuous point have to be defined in order to be removable?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading Thomas' Calculus: Early Transcendentals, 13th edition on my own to prepare for a class. Chapter 2.5 says figure 2.40c has a removable discontinuity, but makes no mention of figure 2.40b, which seems to me to also have a removable discontinuity.

The figures are two plots of generic Real functions, both of which have a point whose value is not what the limit would imply, and neither plot has vertical asymptotes. The only difference between the plots is that 2.40c has a value, albeit not matching up with the limit; whereas 2.40b has no value defined.

Did the book fail to mention that 2.40b also has a removable discontinuity?

Comment: Assuming your description, the b) version is in fact the most standard type of removable discontinuity, as in $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Relevant: [link to the page on Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=AcQJAAAAQBAJ&lpg=SL1-PA97&ots=THPvYKDHXv&dq=Thomas'%20Calculus%3A%20Early%20Transcendentals%20%22removable%20discontinuity%22&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: If the link above is indeed the version you are using, how exactly would you remove the discontinuity in 2.40(c)? (which incidentally *has* a value $f(0)$ defined: namely, $f(0)=1$ per the caption). It has a vertical asymptote, $\lim_{0^-} f = \lim_{0^+} f = \infty$. If it is not the version you are using (which I suspect, as the chapter numbering does not match): can you provide more details on what the book actually says?

Comment: (cont'd) Something in your question regarding $f$ not defined at the point considered makes me wonder if that is the issue: namely (see e.g. [the definition on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html)), for a point $a$ to be a removable discontinuity, $a$ has to belong to the domain of the function in the first place.

Comment: @ClementC Perhaps the book has a typo: 2.40b, which has no value, has a removable discontinuity while 2.40c, which has the wrong value, is not actually a removable discontinuity??

Comment: Can you provide a link to or the text ofnthe book? If not, is the link above indeed to the version of the book you are referring to?

Comment: My book is Thomas' Calculus: Early Transcendentals, 13th Ed., though the example in your Google Books post is very close. Your books' figure a is my book's figure b, and both books' figure c's match.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have that text book so cannot see the pictures you are referring to.  A function, f, is said to be "continuous" at x= a if and only if

(i) f(a) exists

(ii) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists

(iii) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(a)$

(Since (iii) implies that the value of the function and the limit exist, often we just cite (iii)).

A function has a "removable discontinuity at x= a" as long as (i) is true and **either** (ii) or (iii) or both are not.  Thus we can have either f(a) existing, but not equal to the limit, or f(a) not existing.  In either case, since the limit exists, we can "remove" the discontinuity by redefining f(a) to be equal to the limit.

Comment: Note that $(i)$ basically means "$a$ belongs to the domain of $f$." You cannot "remove a discontinuity" at a point that has nothing to do with where $f$ is defined in the first place.